# relation schema curly brackets or round brackets?

Tags: sql, database-schema

When writing the schema for a relation, should you use curly brackets or round brackets? had this confusion after knowing that the attributes in a relation are a set and not a list.

Comment: Is this in theory or on an actual DB platform?  Why not give it a try and find out?  Should be an easy test.

Comment: it's in theory, I want to write the relation schema for the following relation.
relation = Cars.

 Attributes. car_id (the primary key) engine_number, horsepower, torque.

Comment: what I want to know is if the following method is the correct way to write it. 
Cars{car_id, engine_number, horsepower, torque} - where car_id is underlined as its the primary key.